# @ManyToOne mapping doesn't work with joined inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm

I have the following database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `message` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(50000) NOT NULL,
`author_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`last_update_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `author_id_fk` (`author_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `message_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `comment` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 KEY `message_id_fk` (`id`),
 KEY `post_id_fk` (`post_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `message` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `post` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 KEY `message_id_fk` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `post_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `message` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

And the following mapping with hibernate(3.5.4-Final):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
    private Long id = 0L;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Set<Post> posts;
    private Set<Comment> comments;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    public Set<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    public Set<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "message")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Message implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private Author author;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date lastUpdateDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column(name = "text")
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_update_date")
    public Date getLastUpdateDate() {
        return lastUpdateDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateDate(Date lastUpdateDate) {
        this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Comment extends Message {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Post extends Message {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Set<Comment> comments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    public Set<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

The main idea is that Comment and Post are inherited from Message and I would like both of them to have bidirectional relation. But when I run the following code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Author author = new Author();
author.setName("mike");
author.setPassword("123");
author.setEmail("mike@gmail.com");

Post post = new Post();
post.setAuthor(author);
post.setCreationDate(new Date());
post.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
post.setText("Text");
post.setTitle("Title");

Long authorId = (Long)session.save(author);
Long postId = (Long)session.save(post);

tx.commit();
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Unknown column 'author_id' in 'field list'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [org.blogsample.mappingbeans.Post]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
```

**Update**
As @JB Nizet mentioned before I changed `@MappedSuperclass` to `@Entity`, after that I've got another error `mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: org.blogsample.mappingbeans.Comment.author`, this was solved by changing db structure(removed `author_id` from `message` table, added it to each of `comment`, `post` and created foreign keys for this column) and moving author(and getter/setter with mapping) to `Comment`, `Post` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Message` class shouldn't be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`, but with `@Entity`. `@MappedSuperclass` means that entities extending this class inherit columns and associations from the super class, but these columns and associations go in the table of the subclass. `author_id` is not in the `comment` table or in the `post` table. It's in the `message` table.

Moreover `@Table` can only be used with an entity. Not with a mapped superclass, which is only used to inherit fields and associations, but is not mapped to its own table like an entity is.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it in hibernate tutorial. Changed mapping to `@Entity` and got the `mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: org.blogsample.mappingbeans.Comment.authorRef in org.blogsample.mappingbeans.Author.comments`, but I found solution [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=988336). Your comment helped me a lot, thanks.

Comment: I think the solution you found is incorrect.Hibernate won't consider one side as the inverse of the other anymore. See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-558. I think what you're doing is basically impossible. Either make a usinque association from Author to Message. The List<Message> will the contain instances of Post and instances of Message. Or define two ManyToOne associations: one in Post, and one in Comment. You should then have two foreign keys: one in the comment table and one in the post table.

Comment: Yup, I was wrong about my solution. Well I've chosen the second way, I changed db structure(added author_id to `comment` and `post`, removed it from `message` and created foreign keys), after this I was able to remap relations correctly(`@ManyToOne` should have join column, `@OneToMany` should have `mappedBy`.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your answer. I looked up the bug report you refer to, and still there are no answers as to why is this impossible. Why couldn't hibernate deduce the two collections types and use the base-class key?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is exactly the same as the one highlighted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252088/hibernate-manytoone-inheritance-joined-mappedby/22392204).

Have a look at my answer there to see if that helps.