# Hibernate - ManyToOne & Inheritance / JOINED / mappedBy

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I have some problems with inheritance mapping. Here my database structure:

[image]

And associated entities:

#### AbstractEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity<ID extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private ID id;

public ID getId() {
return id;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void setId(ID id) {
this.id = id;
}
```

#### UserAcitvity entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "user_activity")
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ua_id"))
public abstract class UserActivity extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

@ManyToOne(cascade = { MERGE, PERSIST }, fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ua_user_id")
private User user;

...
}
```

#### Comment entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "comment")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cm_id")
public class Comment extends UserActivity {

@ManyToOne(cascade = { MERGE, PERSIST }, fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cm_question_id")
private Question question;

...
}
```

#### Question entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "question")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "qs_id")
public class Question extends UserActivity {

...

@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "question")
private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "question")
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

...
}
```

#### Answer entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "answer")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "asw_id")
public class Answer extends UserActivity {

@ManyToOne(cascade = { MERGE, PERSIST }, fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "asw_question_id")
private Question question;

...
}
```

#### and User entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "user")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "user_id"))
public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

...
@OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE)
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE)
private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

#### Problem:

When I try to save or delete a `User` I get an exceptions:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into user_question (user_user_id, questions_qs_id) values (?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

and:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : 147 = user lacks privilege or object not found: USER_ANSWER
```

Hibernate is trying to create a table: `user_question` and `user_answer` which me **do not need**.

What I should doing for fixes ?

Comment: USER_ANSWER and USER_QUESTION do not appear in your database schema nor your mapping. Some stuff must be missing!

Comment: @Julien Yea I know. This because I don't add [mappedBy](http://goo.gl/tZNmgw). I can not add it through `UserActivity` to `user` field.

Comment: Were you able to solve this while keeping the `ua_user_id` in the `user_activity` table?

Comment: @Snekse Hey. I really don't remember how I did it. Check [full source code in GitHub](https://github.com/dozortsev/AdviceExchange/blob/iss59-jooq/domain/src/main/java/com/dozortsev/adviceexchange/domain/UserActivity.java) hope it will help you. _Investigate it on `iss59-jooq` branch because on `master` it moved on JOOQ from Hibernate_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this by mapping the `ManyToOne` association to `User` generically in the `UserActivity` entity. That's probably too confusing for the JPA provider (Hibernate).

Instead, I think you need to map the association to `User` in **each** of the `Question`, `Answer` and `Comment` entities. Yes, I know that would be duplicated code, but it looks like the only way you will then be able to qualify the `OneToMany` mappings in `User` using the `mappedBy` reference.

For instance, your `Question` entity would have an association defined as:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { MERGE, PERSIST }, fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ua_user_id")
private User questionUser;
```

Depending on how clever (or not) Hibernate is about the above association, you may need to specify the `table="USER_ACTIVITY"` in the `JoinColumn` annotation.

Then the `User` would have the OneToMany as:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="questionUser", cascade = REMOVE)
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Similarly for each of `Answer` and `Comment`.

Of course, I haven't tried this, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably happening because when you set the @OneToMany mapping then the hibernate will create an auxiliary table that will store the id from the entities on the relationship.

In this case you should try the following:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
```

The @JoinColumn annotation will map the relationship without the creation of the auxiliary table, so it's pretty likely this solution will help you in this situation.

Comment: In may case, removing the `mappedBy` was key. See the OPs comment on the question thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try this mapping, this should work as you expect according to [section 2.2.5.3.1.1 of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping):

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE) 
    @JoinColumn(name="user_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
}

@Entity
public class Question {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

The reason why the auxiliary association is created, is that there is no way for Hibernate to know that the Many side of the relation (for example Question) has a foreign key back to User that corresponds to the exact same relation as `User.questions`.

The association `Question.user` could be a completely different association, for example `User.questionCreator` or `User.previousSuccessfulAnswerer`.

Just by looking at `Question.user`, there is no way for Hibernate to know that it's the same association as `User.questions`.

So without the `mappedBy` indicating that the relation is the same, or `@JoinColumn` to indicate that there is no join table (but only a join column), Hibernate will trigger the generic one-to-many association mapping solution that consists in creating an auxiliary mapping table.

The schema misses such association tables, which causes the error that can be solved with the mapping above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unidirectional one-to-many usage in your entity relationship.
Try with..**JoinTable**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE)
@JoinTable(name = "user_question", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "qs_id")})
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
```